# Basic Applet Doesn't Meet Java Safety Standards

Tags: java, security, applet

Essentially I just wanted to make a basic bouncing ball Applett for the heck of it, and it works on my laptop, but when I try to run it online I get a prompt saying it's blocked. I realize this is because of new security measures, so how should I change this up to make it more friendly. Thanks

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class BouncingBall extends Applet implements Runnable{

Random rnd = new Random(500);
int r = rnd.nextInt(70);

int x_pos = 0;
int y_pos = 250;
int radius = 20;
int x_speed = 3;
int y_speed = 3;
int appletsize_x = 500;
int appletsize_y = 500;

private Graphics dbg;
private Image dbImage;

Thread th;

AudioClip bounce;
Image backImage;

public void init(){

}

public void start(){
    Thread th = new Thread(this);

    th.start();
}

public void stop(){

}

public void destroy(){

}

public void run(){
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);

    while(true){

         if(x_pos > appletsize_x - radius){
            x_speed =- r;
        } else if(x_pos < radius){
            x_speed =+ r;
        }

        if(y_pos > appletsize_y - radius){
            y_speed =- r;
        } else if(y_pos < radius){
            y_speed =+ r;
        }

        x_pos += x_speed;
        y_pos += y_speed;

        repaint();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex){

        }



        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    }
}


 public void update(Graphics g){
     if(dbImage == null){
         dbImage = createImage (this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

         dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
        }

        dbg.setColor(getBackground());
        dbg.fillRect(0,0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);

        dbg.setColor(getForeground());
        paint(dbg);

        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x_pos - radius, y_pos - radius, 2*radius, 2*radius);

    g.drawImage(backImage, 0, 0, this);

}

public boolean mouseDown (Event e, int x, int y){
    x_speed =- (x_speed);
    return true;
}

    public boolean keyDown(Event e, int key){
    if(key == Event.LEFT){
        x_speed = -10;
    } else if(key == Event.RIGHT){
        x_speed = 10;
    } else if(key == Event.UP){
        y_speed = -10;
    } else if(key == Event.DOWN){
        y_speed = 10;
    }else if (key == 32){
        x_speed = 0;
        y_speed = 0;
    } else if (key == 45){
        x_speed = 10;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Character: " + (char)key + " Integer value: " + key);
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: On your end, you can't really.  You could get the applet signed, but there's still no guarantee that will solve the problem.  Many browsers simply block applets out right.  You could consider having a look at Java Web Start